# Rank of a Random Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

Consider the following random matrix
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{G}=\left(
               \begin{array}{cc}
                            g_{1,1} & g_{1,2}              \\
                            g_{2,1} & g_{2,2}              \\
               \end{array}
             \right)
\end{equation}
where the entries of $\mathbf{G}$ are i.i.d standard Gaussian random variables. Then what is the rank of this matrix?

I kind feel that $\text{Probablity}(\text{Rank}(\mathbf{G})=2)=1$. But not very confident. Can anyone give a judgement or a proof?

Thank!

Comment: The set of singular matrices has measure zero (more generally, see [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25513/zariski-closed-sets-in-cn-are-of-measure-0)). So, if entries of $\mathrm{G}$ follow a continuous joint distribution (Gaussian or not), the probability that $\mathrm{G}$ is singular is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Intuition says that $P(A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\text{ is singular})=0$ as the set of nonsingular matrices is dense in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Nice asymptotic results can be found, e.g., in [this talk](http://math.colorado.edu/~brider/RMT_workshop/Rudelson_Talk.pdf).

Comment: "Intuition" should have nothing to do with the result. Density does not imply full measure, in general.